# Issue with Filter code and using switch function call within class method, Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field. Kindly help resolve. Issue is withing the filters code as plain serialization is working well

views.py

```
class Job_Application_StateList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = Job_Application_StateSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Job_Application_State.objects.all()
        request_queries = self.request.query_params
        if(request_queries):
            user = self.request.user
            queryset = Job_Application_State.objects.filter(user = user)
            status = request_queries.get('status', None)
            queryset = self.statusFilter(queryset, status)            
        return queryset

    def statusFilter(  self, queryset, args ):    
        switcher = {
            'saved': queryset.filter(saved = True),
            'applied':queryset.filter(applied = True),
            'shortlisted':queryset.filter(shortlisted = True),
        }
        return switcher.get("Invalid Status: ", args)
```

models.py

```
class Job_Application_State(models.Model):
    job = models.ForeignKey(Job, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='applicant_status')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True,
                             on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='application_status')
    saved = models.BooleanField()
    applied = models.BooleanField()
    shortlisted = models.BooleanField()
```

Error:

Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `saved` on serializer `Job_Application_StateSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `str` instance.
Original exception text was: 'str' object has no attribute 'saved'.

Comment: I don't fully understand your `statusFilter` function. Your issue is inside that function for sure. When you return from there, you don't have a queryset anymore. What exactly are you trying to achieve there? What should be inside `args`?

Comment: the error is very likely here `switcher.get("Invalid Status: ", args)`

Comment: no issue with the switcher.get statement, tried commenting it and checking same issue

Comment: the switcher function is supposed to return the queryset ? I am trying to implement switch function in python for the firt time, can suggest a better way ?